# "I should have never dropped my guard so you could <not> stab me in the back."

Tags: negation

from [a song](https://genius.com/Limp-bizkit-counterfeit-lyrics):
**(1)** *I should have never dropped my guard so you **could** stab me in the back*.
my variant:
**(2)** *I should have never dropped my guard so you **couldn't** stab me in the back*.
As far as I understand, "so" in (1) and (2) means "in order that".

Is (1) or (2) correct?
If (1) is and (2) is not, explain please why.
I'm asking this because proceeding from translating into my native language, (1) doesn't make sense and (2) does.

---

Maybe to better figure out this issue, it is worth considering some more sentence.

my examples:
**(3)** *You don't need to eat much so that you **won't** be fat*.
**(4)** *You don't need to eat much so that you **will** be fat*.
As far as I understand, "so that" in (3) and (4) means "in order that".

Proceeding from translating into my native language, (3) makes sense and (4) does not.
Do you agree?
If not, then why not?

---

an update:

To me, (3) makes sense because (3) means (3a):
**(3a)** *You don't need to eat much in order for you **not** to be fat*.

To me, (4) doesn't make sense because (4) means (4a):
**(4a)** *You don't need to eat much in order for you to be fat*.

The meaning which was in my mind when I was creating (3) and (4) was:
**(5)** *You don't need to eat much. Otherwise you will be fat.*
Since (3) and (3a) mean (5), I wrote they make sense.
Since (4) and (4a) don't mean (5), I wrote they don't make sense.

Tell me please why I'm wrong?

Comment: 3 and 4 are not correct.  I'm not quite sure what you are trying to say here.  Perhaps "You don't need to eat that much to get fat". or "You shouldn't eat so much. You'll get fat.

Comment: @BillyKerr I wrote an update below my post. Could you help me please to see the light?

Comment: @Loviii: Your examples still don't work very well. Your (4a) means "Even if you eat very little you can still be thin" (this does not make much sense); (4b) means "You can eat just a little and still be fat" which makes more sense. I think you're possibly confused about "You don't need" - this does _not_ mean "you must not"; it means "it is not necessary", i.e. it is about the absence of a requirement to do something, and not a requirement not to do something.

Comment: @psmears if "_you don't need to eat much_" means "_it's not necessary for you to eat much_", then probably it's correct to use "_you needn't eat much_" instead. Is the following sentence correct?: "_You needn't eat much so that you won't be fat._" Thanks.

Comment: @Loviii: No, "needn't" is just short for "don't need"; it means the same. What you're probably trying to say is "You *mustn't* eat *too* much *or else* you'll *get* fat".

Answer (score 7):

I don't really understand OP's examples #3 or #4<sup>1</sup>, but #1 and #2 are syntactically ambiguous. It's a matter of pragmatics rather than syntax whether the ***so that...*** clause applies to ***my guard*** or the ***dropping*** of that guard.

We logically assume that in #1 it's *the fact of the guard being dropped* which ***enables*** backstabbing, but in #2 it's *the guard itself* which (until dropped) is there to ***prevent*** backstabbing.

---

<sup>1</sup> On closer inspection, #3 and #4 are imho syntactically invalid (or at least, *seriously* non-idiomatic). Valid phrasing would include, for example,...

> *You don't need to eat so much [that] you get fat*

...or more naturally, imho, ***There's no need** to eat so much [that] you get fat* - which effectively means ***You shouldn't** eat so much [that] you get fat.*

Comment: Yes. It seems paradoxical, but both sentences are both grammatically and logically valid and would be understood to mean the same thing. Often, we interpret a sentence based not purely on the grammar of the sentence but on logic and knowledge of the real world. Many jokes are based on this fact. Like there's a classic bad newspaper headline, "Iraqi Head Seeks Arms". Of course what the writer meant was that the leader of Iraq wants weapons, but it could also be read to mean that one body parts wants another.

Answer (score 1):

The line from the song, "I should have never dropped my guard so you could stab me in the back," is colloquial. To make the meaning a little more clear, it would be reasonable (I would say) to insert a word like "just" or only" before "so," e.g. "I should have never dropped my guard *just* so you could stab me in the back." This is still very colloquial but you might find it easier to understand. The idea is that the speaker is lamenting having dropped their guard, because it made an opening for the other person to betray them. They're taking an affect of harshly accusing the other person.

"I should have never dropped my guard so you couldn't stab me in the back" is actually a somewhat different construction. I think you could reasonably expand that to, "I should have never dropped my guard, so *that* you couldn't stab me in the back." In this case, the speaker is elaborating on *why* they should never have dropped their guard, namely because it would have been a ward against being backstabbed. This is a little more removed and clinical in tone—the speaker could conceivably be muttering to themselves under their breath as they say this I think, probably in a movie or the like.

They're almost the same, but not exactly. This kind of speech is a little hard to make sense of systematically because it's so colloquial. These are both kind of special constructions that you would almost always hear in speech—they're kind of hard to write down without losing something.

Comment: I don't really understand "_just so_", but I understand phrases with the word "_way_", e.g. "_in such a way that_". Using it, do you mean: "_I should have never dropped my guard **(just) so** you could stab me in the back._" = "_I should have never dropped my guard **in such a way that** you could stab me in the back._" ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that sounds right.

Comment: Thinking about this a bit more, "just" in this case also connotes futiliy—the person is saying something like, "I let down my guard, and then _all you did_ was to stab me in the back." "All you did" in this case is similar to "just". Like, the other person could have done something nice in response to the speaker letting their guard down, but instead they betrayed them. Saying "just," "only," "all you did," etc. emphasizes the idea that could have done something better but didn't. Again, it's a way of harshly accusing the other person, lambasting them, lamenting their actions, etc.